# How to return list of id's from create nested serialization using django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I created nested serialization but it is return only project name from project model but I want  to return list of ids for one project.
Here you can find create nested serialization  [Created nested serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72428214/how-to-create-three-tables-in-nested-serializer-objects-using-django-rest-framew/72429176?noredirect=1#comment128142570_72429176)

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ProjectSite(models.Model):
    site_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,name='project_site_name')
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, 
    related_name="projectid")

class Assignment(models.Model):
    assignment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    assignment_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    site_id = models.ForeignKey(ProjectSite,related_name="projectsiteidkey", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assigned_to_id = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',related_name="assignedtoidfkey",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the `SerializerMethodField` to get those value.

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    site_ids = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only = True)
    
    ...

    def get_site_ids(self, obj):
        return list(obj.projectid.values_list('id').distinct())
```

Comment: but it will return nested array right

Comment: Sorry, but what's this?

Comment: def get_site_site(self, obj):
        return list(obj.projectid.values_list('sitename').distinct()) it is return sitename along with siteid.  but I would like to return like this {{sitename:test1, siteid:1},{sitename:test2, siteid:2}}

Comment: I am trying to return response like this {{sitename:test1, siteid:1},{sitename:test2, siteid:2}}

Comment: Then you can use just the serializer of the `ProjectSite` model. Do you have it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245441/discussion-between-srinuvas-bathula-and-david-lu).